# Clicking navbar doesn't scroll to correct location, but typing in URL bar does

Tags: html, url, navbar

HTML for Nav bar...

```
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">

    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="#hero">Home</a></li>

      <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#portfolio">The World</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#journal">Journal</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
    <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
  </nav><!-- .navbar -->
```

Additionally, I have the sections I want using the id= tag. For example...

```
 <div id="hero" name="hero" class="home">
 <div id="about" class="paddsection">
 <div id="portfolio" class="paddsection">
 <div id="journal" class="paddsection">
 <div id="contact" class="paddsection">
```

The strange part is that "hero", "services", and "portfolio" all work when I click them in the navbar. However, "journal" and "contact" just scroll to a location within the "portfolio" section. Additionally, if I manually type in #journal or #contact into the URL bar, then it works! I'm lost, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your browser's cache is full, try pressing ctrl + alt f5 to clear and update. Also try to test in another browser if possible.